# How to convert 10digit int to date

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

How to convert 1640704675 into date.

```
extension Date {
    var millisecondsSince1970:Int64 {
        return Int64((self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0).rounded())
    }

    init(milliseconds:Int64) {
        self = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(milliseconds) / 1000)
    }
}

//Convert date to another formate.
func dateConvertion(date: Date, dateFormat: String) -> String {
    let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
    dateFormater.dateFormat = dateFormat
    dateFormater.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    let dateStr = dateFormater.string(from: date)
    return dateStr
}
```

Try to convert 10 digit Int to Date //

```
if let modifiedDate = callValue?.updatedDate{
        let dateValue = String(modifiedDate).toDate(.isoDateTimeMilliSec) ?? Date()
        let finalDate = dateConvertion(date: dateValue, dateFormat: formaterMonthDateyear)
        print("finalDate \(finalDate)")
}
```

Its shown current date value when converting int value to date

Comment: The second block of code in your question isn't calling the functions in the first block of code. what is `toDate`? Whatever it is, it's returning nil, so you're getting the current date back from it.

Comment: I don't see any part of the code where the number `1640704675` appears. So how is this about converting 1640704675 into anything? Also (and related), do not show us code that contains unknowns; we have no way to know what `callValue?.updatedDate` refers to, as you have not shown it — and we have no reason at all to believe that it is 1640704675 if that's the idea here.

Comment: Your sample date seems to be a date in seconds, not milliseconds. If you convert it to a Date like this: `Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(1640704675))` you get `2021-12-28 15:17:55 +0000` which seems reasonable.

Comment: Your integer is the number of seconds since 1970

Comment: @matt callValue?.updatedDate is Int value  1640704675

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, it looks like your integer value is a number of seconds since 1970, not milliseconds. Just use the existing `init(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval)` method, and cast your integer to a TimeInterval:

And call it like this:

```
print(Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(1640704675)))
```

As mentioned in a comment, that displays `2021-12-28 15:17:55 +0000`, which looks like a recent, valid date.

Comment: Whats the purpose to add a initializer that's already present?

Comment: Btw if the intent is to support integers you should make it a generic initializer to support any binary integer.

Comment: Leo, good point. The `init(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval)` init method is already there. That'll teach me to edit an answer while doing 3 other things. I edited my answer to use the existing method instead.